Excel data getting modified after uploading
while uploading excel sheet 2014271415063010000 this number is automatically modified to 2014271415063010050 when I retrieve cell value.
the data type in database is varchar.
I want same number which is in excel sheet.
I have tried every solution from chat gpt but still cannot able to resolve this issue.
please help
public static String convertEnglishToMarathi(String marathiNumber) {
StringBuilder englishNumber = new StringBuilder();
    if(marathiNumber!=null && marathiNumber!="" ) {
    // Iterate through each character in the Marathi number and convert
    for (char marathiDigit : marathiNumber.toCharArray()) {
        // Check if the character is a Marathi digit
        if (englishMapTOmarathi.containsKey(marathiDigit)) {
            englishNumber.append(englishMapTOmarathi.get(marathiDigit));
        } else {
            // If it's not a Marathi digit, keep it as is
            englishNumber.append(marathiDigit);
        }
    }
    return englishNumber.toString();

    }else {
        return null;
    }

}

this method I am using now. and it didn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ok I found the solution, so while uploading I just added apostrophe ' before the number and Excel started considering it as a string
